# DNS + DHCP in home lab

Tags: dns, dhcp, openbsd

Setting up a home lab.

I was originally planning on using static ips for everything and then powerdns + poweradmin for DNS.

Recently though it dawned on me that it would be a lot simpler to just use DNS + DHCP tied together, which apparently is possible.

Running OpenBSD for my router, no DHCP service yet.

What service should I use for DNS + DHCP on OpenBSD?

How does the DHCP client determine the hostname of a server, in order to provide that data to the DNS server?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by the last sentence. Are you asking how the DNS server makes records of the client's hostname and address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISC's DHCP and DNS server (BIND). They are, as far as I know, still the most-used daemons for both. Another option is using NSD as name server.

You can also set it up with the former first and the latter second since it's a lab environment and the goal is, after all, to learn about these daemons. No?